# How to solve optimization problem with matrix constraint?

Tags: convex-optimization

I'm working with the following optimization problem below.
$$\min_{\Pi} \left[
\frac{1}{4 \lambda
   }\left((\Pi\vec{1}-s)^T K(\Pi\vec{1}-s) + \left(\Pi^T \vec{1}-t\right)^T K \left(\Pi^T \vec{1}-t\right)\right)-\text{Tr}[\Pi K]
\right]$$

Here, $\lambda$ is a scalar, $\Pi$ and $K$ are $n\times n$ matrices, and $s,t$ are $n\times 1$ probability vectors (i.e. the components sum up to $1$). Also $K$ is PSD and $\Pi$ has elements summing up to $1$.

I was able to empirically show that the diagonal elements of $\Pi^{*}$, the optimal $\Pi$, correspond to $\frac{s+t}{2}$ regardless of the choice of $\lambda$, but I am having difficulty showing this to be the case theoretically. Does anyone have any advice? I tried for the case when $n=2$ using Lagrange multipliers and even then it gets very messy.

I set up a Lagrange multipier where the matrix constraint $1^T \Pi 1=1$, and I end up getting as my first order conditions

$$2K [(\Pi+\Pi^T) \vec{1}-(s+t)] \vec{1}^T - K - \lambda \vec{1}\vec{1}^T = 0$$
and
$$1-\vec{1}^T \Pi \vec{1}=0.$$

I just don't see where to go from here. I'd like to use these to show $\vec{diag(\Pi^*)} = \frac{1}{2}(\vec{s+t})$. Also, how do I come up with KKT duals when every element of $\Pi$ must be nonnegative?

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: For $n \ge 2$, the problem is generally unbounded, unless there is an additional constraint, such as all elements of $P \ge 0$.. Presuming this additional constraint is added, I did not find agreement with your assertion on any of several instances I generated with random s and t probability vectors and random PSD K, and numerically solved as QP. However, your assertion appears to be true, if also K is a (positive) multiple of the Identity matrix, but not true if K is a general PSD diagonal matrix.

Comment: Oh so yeah also all the elements of $\Pi$ are nonnegative, yes.

Comment: Can you tell me which instances gave a counterexample?

Comment: Every instance I tried, except for the exceptions I mentioned. Maybe all your inputs are more structured specials cases. What instances did you solve and how do they map against the special cases I mentioned?

Comment: I used K= [1,4; 4,1], s=[.5,.5], t=[.2,8] for a 2D case and K=[1,0,0;0,1,0;0,0,1], s=[.1,.4,.5], t=[.4,.2,.4] for the 3D case. Both of these got me a diagonal with s+t / 2.

Comment: And how would I incorporate the constraint that all elements are greater than or equal to 0 in a Lagrangian?

Comment: KKT conditions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions. QP, so satisfies Linearity constraint qualification. I am doubting you will find a closed form solution.

Comment: Does that mean there isn't a way to theoretically show the diagonal would be the average of s and t?

Comment: Well, certainly not possible if there are counterexamples.  Unless I made a mistake, or the inputs are further restricted than what I did. But your hypothesis seems to hold for K being a positive multiple of the Identity matrix,

Comment: Can you please give me a specific counterexample? I still have not found any counter-examples on my end so I'd like to check myself.

Comment: In MATLAB notation: s=[.5;.5];t=[1;0];K=diag([1;2]); results in optimal P=diag([0;1]), optimal objective =-1.90625.  However, using P=diag((s+t)/2)=diag([.75;.25]) results in objective=-1.240625, which is inferior, so not optimal.

Comment: Forgot to mention that counterexample is with $\lambda=10$. Same optimal solution with $\lambda=1$, but different optimal solution for $\lambda=0.1$.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your Matlab code with me? Greatly appreciate it! Email is pitcany@gmail.com